# Declaring a field as a bit (as a single bit, as opposed to a byte multiple) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, bit

> C# 6.0 in a Nutshell by Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari (O’Reilly).
>
> Copyright 2016 Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari, 978-1-491-92706-9.

introduces, at page 312, BitArrays as one of the Collection types .NET provides:

> **BitArray**
>
> A BitArray is a dynamically sized collection of compacted bool values.
>   It is more memory-efficient than both a simple array of bool and a
>   generic List of bool, because it uses only one bit for each value,
>   whereas the bool type otherwise occupies one byte for each value.

It's nice to have the possibility of declaring a collection of bits instead of working with bytes when you are interested in binary values only, but what about declaring a single bit field ?

like:

```
public class X
{
    public [bit-type] MyBit {get; set;}
}
```

.NET does not support it ?

The existent posts on that touch the topic talk about setting individual bits within, ultimately, a byte variable. I am asking if, once .NET thought of supporting working with bit variables, in a collection, if it also supports declaring a non-collection such variable.

Comment: The simplest solution, is to use `bool`, that's all what you need.

Comment: Looks like you did not even read the text's question :). I am inquiring about the point raised by the author when explaining why BitArrays was introduced - performance-wiser if you are interested in working with binary values only. I am aware the I can work with bool variables, but these are declared as a byte.

Comment: Sorry @Veverke, completely skimmed over the `BitArray` excerpt somehow...

Comment: What would be the perceived benefit here? It's not like the remaining 7 bits in that byte can be used for anything else.

Comment: `[Flags] enum myBits : byte { bit1 = 1 }` would be the best approximation you can get in C# apart from `BitArray`.

Comment: @Phil1970: I do not see what difference there is between what you propose and a bool variable (I think it is stored as a byte).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Well, your remark implies that the CLR's atomic storage unit is a byte (which I think it is), and your question follows logically from that. On the other hand, I still think my question also follows from having being allowed somehow to work with bits instead of a whole byte with BitArray - asking then to be able to do so with a single bit instead of a collection of them.

Comment: All that's happening is that bitarray, behind the scenes, is doing exactly the bit manipulations that you've found elsewhere - they didn't fundamentally make bits addressable and individually *writable*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: My question was not indeed motivated by any specific requirement - other than wanting to benefit from the same performance benefit of BitArray when I need only one such bit instead of many. (I can of course have a BitArray with a single element, but thought there must be something else).

Comment: E.g. here's `BitArray`'s [`Set` method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/bitarray.cs,209) where you can see the bit shifting.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: So are you saying that a BitArray with 3 elements is a byte where they manipulate 3 of its bits ? Well, you are being backed by the source code :)

Comment: Actually, it's an `int` and you're wasting 29 bits. `BitArray` is efficient for memory if you're using lots of bits (or at least multiples of 32) - and note that while you keep saying performance, all that's actually efficient here is memory usage.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: you are definitely right on the "performance" remark, I had the feeling myself I was used the wrong term.

Comment: Well for the `enum` alternative, it could be used when you need to set a specific bit usually when working with data that is encoded with bit. As item in a `enum` are named, it might lead to more readable code than using `BitArray` in some use cases.

Answer (score 3):

So your question is whether .NET supports this or not. The answer is no.

Why? It's fundamentally possible to have such a feature. But the demand is really low. It's better to invest the developer time elsewhere.

If you want to make use of memory below the byte granularity you will need to build this yourself. `BitArray` is not intrinsic to the runtime. It manipulates the bits of some bigger type (I think it's `int`-based). You can do the same thing.

`BitVector32` is a built-in struct that you can use to individually address 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [.Net reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/bitarray.cs,19ad3f494f0dc7f6), `BitArray` internally stores the values within an `Array` of `int`

```
public BitArray(int length, bool defaultValue) {
    ...
    m_array = new int[GetArrayLength(length, BitsPerInt32)];
    m_length = length;

    int fillValue = defaultValue ? unchecked(((int)0xffffffff)) : 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_array.Length; i++) {
        m_array[i] = fillValue;
    }

    _version = 0;
}
```

So the least thing that gets allocated with a BitArray is already an entire `int` for the reference and even more if you store data in it. This also makes sense since the memory the used for addressing anything is already in data words. Those are - depending on the architecture - at least 4 bytes long already.

You can of course define an own type for a single Bit to store, but this will also take at least a byte - if not even a complete word and a byte due to being a reference type - to do so. Memory is allocated to a program by the OS in terms of memory addresses, which usually address bytes, so anything less is not entirely useful.

It takes a lot of binary values to store, to even make up for the space already lost by using the type in the first place, so the only really useful application of this technique of storing bits is when you've got lots of them, so that you can profit of the 8:1 memory ratio.